# Returned null of the left join'ed tables field, what i missed?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables related each other. I left join them over id fileds. But the last joined tables filed returns null.

```
SELECT
    ila.ilac_adi AS ilacADI,
    ila.firma AS ilacFIRMA, 
    piy.pk_ay AS ilacAY, 
    kur.kurum_adi AS ilacIL 
FROM piyasa_kontrol piy
LEFT JOIN ilaclar ila 
    ON piy.ilac_id = ila.eski_sistem_id_nolari
LEFT JOIN kurum_adlari kur
    ON kur.id = piy.pk_il
```

`ilacIL` (`kur.kurum_adi`) field returns null

I tried `GROUP BY piy.id,` and got only 1 row and `ilacIL` is still null.

Where did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Left Outer Join**, returns **NULL** when

- IF record matched between **Left table(main)** and **Right table** & **Selected field** from Right table is **BLANK** in table
- **Else** Record not matched between them

In your case **ilacIL (kur.kurum_adi)** might be **BLANK** or **record not matched**

Comment: Thank you SJnawali but field is not blank. Actually, after first join, everything is ok. But when i join the third table, any column in 3rd table returned null.

Comment: Sorry i got it. When i transfer 3rd table from SQLite to MySQL i forgot the id row is Auto Increment. Because of that reason there is no match over id. My mistake. Thank you.